# Google Dataflow with UDF doesn't work - runtime error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use Dataflow to migrate data from MongoDB to BigQuery using flex template MongoDB_to_BigQuery. I want to transform data using UDF functions but the runtime error occurs.

I have two different commands:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run {job_name} --project={project} --region={region} --template-file-gcs-location={template_file_gcs_location} --network={network} --subnetwork={subnetwork} --parameters outputTableSpec={project}:{dataset}.{table_name},mongoDbUri=$MONGO_DB_URI,database={database},collection={collection},userOption={user_option}
```

This one works correctly but imports raw data. When I add additional parameters with UDF functions:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run {job_name} --project={project} --region={region} --template-file-gcs-location={template_file_gcs_location} --network={network} --subnetwork={subnetwork} --parameters outputTableSpec={project}:{dataset}.{table_name},mongoDbUri=$MONGO_DB_URI,database={database},collection={collection},userOption={user_option},javascriptDocumentTransformGcsPath={udf_transformation_location},javascriptDocumentTransformFunctionName={udf_function_name}
```

I get

```
com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.common.UncaughtExceptionLogger - The template launch failed.
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=x.x.x.x:X, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:287)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbUtils.getMongoDbDocument(MongoDbUtils.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbUtils.getTableFieldSchemaForUDF(MongoDbUtils.java:163)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery.run(MongoDbToBigQuery.java:101)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery.main(MongoDbToBigQuery.java:88)
```

Variable `udf_transformation_location` is in format `gs://` and the function in JS does nothing:

```
function process(inJson) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(inJson);

  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: Are you sure the Dataflow worker can access that gs file?

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/extend-your-dataflow-template-with-udfs

Note: The Dataflow worker service account used must have access to the GCS object (JavaScript file) containing your UDF function. Refer to Dataflow user docs to learn more about Dataflow worker service account.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed question!

There's a bit of nuance here when you use UDFs (or if your option is to flatten elements). The pipeline launcher needs to connect to instance to fetch documents and obtain their schema.

It seems that the code is having issues connecting to MongoDB in that launcher phase.

Now why the workers can reach MongoDB (since without UDFs it works fine) and the launcher doesn't, is not clear, but we are talking by different VMs there.

Are you relying on any network tags? If any tag is needed on the launcher, you can use `--experiments=use_network_tags_for_flex_templates={TAG}`.